# Can Googlebot read CamelCase file names?

Tags: seo, google, googlebot

This has been a question I have been wondering for quite some time now.

Can Googlebot, and other search engine crawlers, read file names (such as images) that are in CamelCase?

For example, if I have an image saved as `ThisIsMyImage.jpg`, can Googlebot detect that as being a file name of `This Is My Image`, or is it best to save it as `this-is-my-image.jpg` or `this is my image.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google reads hyphens (-) as word separators in URL's so they can quite easily distinguish `this-is-my-image.jpg` as `This is my image`. From a readability perspective, we always follow the format of hyphenating words in file names.

You can learn more about this [here](http://www.internetofficer.com/seo/google-word-separator/) and to quote from the article:-

> Google has confirmed that the point (.), the comma (,) and the hyphen (-) are valid word separators in URL’s.